# Do banks automatically replace damaged chip cards?

Tags: credit-card, chip-card

In an [answer I wrote](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/176406/17569) about credit card fallback, I said

> If your bank starts receiving lots of indications that your chip isn't working, they may simply just send you a new card. After all, you're clearly more vulnerable to fraud now, and they don't like that.

But then I realized that I don't actually know if banks will automatically send you a new card, or if they just record the fallback, or if they simply ignore it.

Does anyone know if banks will actually do this?  Is this something that a European bank (which has lots of EMV experience) might do but a US bank (which is new to the whole thing) might not?  Or is the fallback indicator simply for the sake of the payment networks and irrelevant to the bank?

Comment: This probably depends greatly on the individual bank.

Comment: I'd imagine that the every day consumer would get tired of inserting their card three times and then swiping, after learning that their chip is broken, and contact the bank themselves.

Comment: @PeteB. - I'm sure there are banks who could do it who don't, but I'm looking to see whether there are *any* banks who do.  If **none** do, or it's not a normal thing, that's significant.  If some do and some don't, that's a valid answer.

Comment: The simple answer is "no".  It's a good idea but there are no systems in place for that.

Answer (score 2):

They will not automatically send you a card, but they will send you a card if you ask. You will need to set up your new card with a pin and have your old card destroyed.

Comment: It should also be noted that they shouldn't charge a fee for this, even if they normally charge a fee for lost/stolen card replacements - the card is faulty, and that's their problem.